# How to send proper xml file with Next.js new app router?

Tags: xml, next.js

I found the [doc](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/route-handlers#non-ui-responses) about sending non-UI content with `route.ts`, but it doesn't behave like intended.

It just sends back a string, and the browser doesn't see it as an XML file. It just displays text, non-parsed in tags.

Should something else be added for it to be recognized as an xml file? How would you do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Response` is setting the content type to `text/plain` by default; this is why the browser is displaying it that way. You could remedy that by setting the correct type, like so:

```js
// app/api/route.js

export async function GET() {
  const xmlContent = `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
  <rss version="2.0">
   
  <channel>
    <title>Next.js Documentation</title>
    <link>https://nextjs.org/docs</link>
    <description>The React Framework for the Web</description>
  </channel>
   
  </rss>`;

  return new Response(xmlContent, { headers: { "Content-Type": "text/xml" } });
}
```